# GCP Vision async_batch_annotate_files timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision, vision-api

I have been using the gcp vision api pdf extraction for a month, but recently I am getting timeout errors.

```
type=vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)
The error is 'Operation did not complete within the designated timeout.'
```

Perhaps it is infrastructure issues as the codebase hasn't changed but how can I find out from Google?

Comment: How long have you been facing this problem? Is it failing all the time or only sometimes?

Comment: I am having the same issue today, been using it for over a month too. Maybe it is some issue with the API? I hope because so far no clue.

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: Same problem here, looks to be a problem with async for some reason. Just tested with batch_annotate_files instead and I received a response

Comment: Its been working perfectly for a month, but is not working anymore.  It looks like it is partly processing the files, as I can see them on gcp storage but the server is not responding to the client properly.

Comment: The async operations were finishing yesterday, but took a long time to finish. Seems like you were using the client library. How long do you poll the operation before you give up?

Comment: normally I use 120 seconds,  yesterday I had it for 10 minutes

Comment: We just had the same problem today again. Seems to be intermittant...

Comment: I did a run last night 20/5 and it processed ok

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is working again,  the logs and metrics say it was always up but that was obviously not the case